# Evaluating an expression

Tags: python

I was working on a small coding question about implementing a method for evaluating a simple expression.

Others methods are working correctly but I keep getting "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'evaluation' " . I can't figure out where is the problem.

```py
class BinOp(Expr):
  def __init__(self, operator, left: Expr, right: Expr ):
    self.operator = operator
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
  def evaluation(self):

      if(self.operator == "+"):
        return Number(self.left.evaluation() + self.right.evaluation())
      else: 
        if(self.operator == "-"):
          return Number(self.left.evaluation() - self.right.evaluation())
        else:
          if(self.operator == "*"):
            return Number(self.left.evaluation() * self.right.evaluation())
          else:
            if(self.operator == "/"):
              return Number(self.left.evaluation() / self.right.evaluation())
```

Comment: Consider using `elif` to reduce indentation (see [`if` Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements)).

Comment: Can you provide an example of creating an instance of `BinOp`? Also, what is `Expr`?

Comment: Consider using [operator module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given us the code that's calling this, but here's probably what's happening:

`left` and `right` are not `Expr`s, they're `float`s. Python doesn't enforce type coercion like this - the notation you use here (`left: Expr`) is called "type *hinting*", and is solely for the purposes of documentation and APIs - it's not in any way enforced by the language as it's running. If someone does

```
myOp = BinOp('+', 3.5, 4.8)
```

then `BinOp()` gets passed a string and two floats - *not `Expr`s*. This is different from languages like C, where the arguments might be automatically coerced, or Java, which might throw a compile-time error. At which point the error is obvious - floats don't have an `evaluation()` method.

I don't know where your `Expr` class comes from, but you might need to coerce `left` and `right` to `Expr()` inside the `BinOp` constructor:

```
def __init__(self, op, left, right):
    self.operator = op
    self.left = Expr(left)
    self.right = Expr(right)
```

if `Expr` is a well-designed data structure, than passing an instance to a constructor should probably produce a copy, which is sufficient for our purposes.

Comment: This is exactly where I missed. Thank you very much!
The problem only occurs when I call left and right, I am sorry for not clarifying this better, it is more like I don't know what is wrong with them.